# How to get Click event on MvxLinearLayout items\childeren?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

How can I get a click event on the items\childeren of a MvxLinearLayout view?

I tried View.OnClickListener, but it doesnt get recognized.

I tried doing it with ListViews but they do not scale well when they are nested in other ListViews or LinearLayouts (its a big list of list, single scroll). Nested LinearLayouts display perfectly and updat good with bindings, only the items are not clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a custom adapter for the MvxLinearLayout that inherited from MvxAdapterWithChangedEvent.

Then overide the GetBindableView() and attach click event to all incomming items.

To regulate the events you can hookup to DataSetChanged event, when items get removed or added on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a click event to any layout you want. This is an example:

```
<LinearLayout
    local:MvxBind="Click SomeCommand" />
```

Comment: tnx, I will try it asap